# Best practice in introducing translated React components in a website?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, localization

I have to maintain a website with a lot of javascript UI in-house components. In order to reduce the volume of code to maintain and use an heavily tested framework, I would like to migrate some components to React / JSX. This seems not to be a pain so far.

However, these components are localized. Their translation is rendered on server side, before sending the component to the client.

To keep the same architectural principles, my idea was to use Node.js as a middleware to replace on the fly any "{{...}}" to its localized version and serve a "rendered" react component to the client.
But this is more like a hack and I am pretty sure it could lead to performance issue.

Is there a common (or best) practice to handle such a scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

common best practice is to wrap localisable strings into React-components and supply translations with your app bundle, so user would be able to switch languages and date/number formatting on the fly.

You may want to look into most popular components to get it working out of the box:

- [react-i18next](https://react.i18next.com/)
- [react-intl](https://formatjs.io/docs/getting-started/installation/)
- [react-intl-universal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-intl-universal)
- [LinguiJS](https://lingui.js.org/)

Here is an example from `react-i18next`:

```
<div>Just simple content</div>
<div>
  Hello <strong title="this is your name">{name}</strong>, you have {count} unread message(s). <Link to="/msgs">Go to messages</Link>.
</div>


<div>{t('simpleContent')}</div>
<Trans i18nKey="userMessagesUnread" count={count}>
  Hello <strong title={t('nameTitle')}>{{name}}</strong>, you have {{count}} unread message(s). <Link to="/msgs">Go to messages</Link>.
</Trans>
```

Answer (score 0):

[react-intl-universal](https://github.com/alibaba/react-intl-universal) is strongly recommended.

- It's much more simple to use than other libs. (simple API)
- It could be used not only in React.Component but also in Vanilla JS.
- [react-intl-universal-extract](https://github.com/alibaba/react-intl-universal/blob/master/packages/react-intl-universal-extract/README.md) helps you manage locale data. Not need to maintain the locale files manually anymore.
- [Demo of react-intl-universal](https://fe-tool.com/react-intl-universal)